# AndroidRuntime Caused by: java.lang.unsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load tfp_jni: findLibrary returned null

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

So, it looks like there are a lot of issues like mine out there but not sure any of them are related to my issue.  OK.  I have an Android project that uses an SDK as a referenced library.  The SDK contains C++, so I am using the android-ndk-r9 library.  The SDK that I reference in my Android project is a JNI library (Oooooo - scary stuff).  Oh yeah, don't let me forget to mention armeabi-v7a (which appears to be another scary subject).  My error occurs when this line is executed:

```
 System.loadLibrary("tfp_jni");
```

tfp_jni is really a libtfp_jni.so file under the armeabi-v7a folder in libs folder of my SDK library project.  That SDK library project contains an Android.mk file.  I do not think the code is getting in there.  But here is the contents of that .mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := tfp-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libtfp_jni.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then in my Android project, I have a jni folder containing an Android.mk and an Application.mk.  Here are the contents:

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_CAMERA:=off

include $(INNERID_ANDROID_ROOT)/Android.mk
include $(OPENCV_ANDROID_ROOT)/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```

**Environment Variables**

[image: Environment Variables]

**Paths and Symbols - Includes**

[image: Paths and Symbols - Includes]

All other tabs are empty except for the Source Location and Output Location, which displays the project folder.

**Android project & Preferences**

[image: Android project & Preferences]

I have tried various other answers from the similar questions on Stackoverflow with no success.  Please let me know if there is anything else you need to see and I'll provide the additional information as soon as possible.

**New Image**

[image: Imgur]

Correction!  The apk is in the verify-demo-nolic project /bin folder.  The Referenced Library tfp_java.jar is the SDK library project.  You can see from Finder that the .so file is in libs.  Does this help?

Comment: .apk files are just fancy zip files, so open the .apk file with a zip file tool and see if the .so file is making it into the apk.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Sorry!  Where is the apk?

Comment: From memory, perhaps in the bin/ folder under your project tree, if you've recently done a build-to-install.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - No it's not there.

Comment: Ok, so now we have to figure out why.  Did you run ndk-build?  Or are you using some fancy front end tool that is supposed to compile the library and copy it to the project tree?

Comment: I added a new picture to show the SDK.  I think we may be looking in the wrong direction.  Maybe.  Maybe not. THANK YOU!!!!  :-)

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Did that last image help?  We use CMake to build the SDK project and then we reference it in our demo app.  I can see that CMake is including the .so library in the SDK.  Should the demo app apk contain the SDK library that I've added as a Referenced Library?  Will you please help me understand your last statement?  Thank you.

Comment: Last I heard, you cannot put a .so in a jar and have it make it into the apk; rather, you'll have to either reference a project in which it is found, or specifically copy it to the appropriate subfolder of the libs folder of the application project that uses it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - You're a GENIUS!!!!  I was using someone else's Eclipse project (hence his settings).  I had all of the environment variables set and everything LOOKED correct.  But then after reading your "Did you run ndk-build?" question above, I looked at the configuration for Builder Settings in Eclipse and saw that the Build command was ${NDKROOT}/${NDKBUILDCMD}.  Aaaaarrrrrrrg!  I had the environment variable set for NDKROOT but not for NDKBUILDCMD.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Answer the question and I'll give you as many points as I can.  I'm not sure how points work just yet.  So far, it seems that I can only up vote 1 point.  We'll see.  :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A number of things must occur for the linkage to work

1. The native library must be compiled to an .so file for the appropriate ABI(s) - this is typically accomplished via the `ndk-build` script/batch file, though it can also be done using a generated stand alone toolchain.  IDE projects may want to configure running this as a custom build step.
2. The native library must get packaged in the application .apk.  If it was built from a jni/ folder under an application project directory, then `ndk-build` probably copied it into an ABI-appropriate subdirectory of the libs/ folder of the project.  *However, if the native library belongs to a distinct Android library, extra steps may be required*.  In particular, a .so **cannot be obtained by the build system from a library .jar** and so one associated with library code must either by explicitly copied under the libs/ folder of the client project, or else found by referencing a library project directory tree (**not a lonely .jar**) which includes it.
3. The installer on the device must decide that one of the .so files contained in the .apk is appropriate for the device's ABI (architecture) and copy it out of the .apk into the install directory for use.
4. The runtime linkage names of the jni functions (downstream of any compiler name-mangling) must match those which the VM is looking for.  Typically, problems here come up from not correctly encoding the java fully qualified class name in the native function name.  The `javah` tool is intended to help avoid such mistakes, though with care it can be done manually.

Each of these steps presents a potential breakdown, so debugging an unsatisfied link can be approached by trying to find the first stage at which the .so file goes missing.

Comment: my .so files are in libs what should I do. I couldn't understand,please help.