# Android java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError - couldn't find "libffmpeg.so"

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, ffmpeg, android-ndk

i have build this project with eclipse https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme and it is running fine , but when i try to build this project in android studio i am error in my Ffmpeg class ,i have copy all the file from my running demo which i made in eclipse to my android studio project directory , i will post my directory structure and build.gradle , please anyone guide me? please see the below

```
Process: com.google.android.apps.watchme, PID: 6330
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.apps.watchme-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libffmpeg.so"
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.Ffmpeg.<clinit>(Ffmpeg.java:22)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.VideoStreamingConnection.open(VideoStreamingConnection.java:71)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerService.startStreaming(StreamerService.java:73)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity.startStreaming(StreamerActivity.java:161)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity.access$200(StreamerActivity.java:39)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity$1.onServiceConnected(StreamerActivity.java:55)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1208)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1225)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

[image]

and in JNI function

[image]

Comment: Where is your jni folder places ? Place it inside src->main->jni

Comment: yes i have created the folder in the same location you can check in the screen shot

Comment: please see in the screen shot

Comment: try this :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992329/androidruntime-caused-by-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-load-tfp-jni

Comment: i have copy all the file from my running demo which i made in eclipse to my android studio project directory

Comment: change your jni folder name to jniLibs

Comment: any specific reason to change the folder name to  jniLibs, because bydefault android studio will create jni for you

Comment: If you read the README.md it says "under src/main/jniLibs/armeabi" So that's why I said that try it once

Comment: ok i will try that

Comment: no same error , any other solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108350/discussion-between-achin-and-rakshit-nawani).

Answer (score 1):

have you added “libffmpeg.so” file for all abis?( 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips', 'mips64')
if not, then generate apk for available abis only. 
suppose have libffmpeg.so file for 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a' abis. then you need to add following into ending of android {} part of app.gradle.

```
splits {

    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
    abi {

        // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
        enable true

        // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
        // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.

        // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
        reset()

        // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.


        include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a'
        // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
        universalApk false
    }
}
```